# foreman error while "Getting Started with Node.js on Heroku"

Tags: node.js, heroku, foreman

I am in the midst of "Getting Started with Node.js on Heroku", where I want to "Run the app locally" by:
**$ foreman start web**
(cf. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#run-the-app-locally)

It says:
/usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb:54:in `run': undefined method`spawn' for Process:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb:53:in `chdir'
    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb:53:in`run'
    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb:356:in `spawn_processes'
    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb:353:in`upto'
    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb:353:in `spawn_processes'
    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb:352:in`each'
    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb:352:in `spawn_processes'
    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb:57:in`start'
    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/cli.rb:41:in `start'
    from /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in`**send**'
    from /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in`invoke_command'
    from /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in`start'
    from /usr/bin/foreman:15

(Running on Mac OS 10.7.5)

Any ideas what may help? Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem won OSX 10.7.5.  I updated  to Ruby 2.2 and tried several versions of foreman 0.75, 0.77. 0.78. No luck so far…

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/473.
Seems to be related to an old version of foreman or ruby.